# Distribution of transformed lognormal random variable

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution, transform

I was wondering:

if $X \sim N(0,1)$ then
$P=\exp(x)$ is lognormally distributed.
However, what is the distribution of
$P=c\exp(x)-d$
Will it still be lognormally distributed?

Comment: Can't be, because $P$ will have support in $(-d, \infty)$. The log-normal is only closed under power and multiplicative transformations, not affine transformations.

Comment: @tchakravarty but isn't subtracting a constant, d, simply shifting the realizations by d without affecting the distribution?

Comment: Yes, but note that there is no normal distribution $Y$, which when exponentiated, will give you $P$.

Comment: @iJatrat "Shifting" certainly affects the distribution; a shifted lognormal is no longer lognormal (the ordinary lognormal is not a location family)

Comment: FWIW, it's a [three-parameter lognormal](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172030/three-parameter-lognormal-distribution). Giving it a name doesn't really add any information that isn't already perfectly apparent from the construction of this distribution, however.